# Adjusting coordinates for NSTableView draggingSession

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I've been banging my head to the wall for about two weeks, I've looked at all the Apple documentation available plus hundreds of websites looking for a hint to solve my problem. I'm implementing:

```
-(void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView draggingSession:(NSDraggingSession *)session willBeginAtPoint:(NSPoint)screenPoint forRowIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)rowIndexes
```

The problem that I'm having is that the icon for the dragged files shows up in a different coordinate system and I can't seem to find a way to make the icon show on the screenPoint where the drag began. I've looked into all [tableView convert* ] methods in several combinations without success. Below is the code I'm currently using.

```
-(void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView draggingSession:(NSDraggingSession *)session willBeginAtPoint:(NSPoint)screenPoint forRowIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)rowIndexes {

[session enumerateDraggingItemsWithOptions:NSDraggingItemEnumerationConcurrent
                                   forView:tableView
                                   classes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSPasteboardItem class], nil]
                             searchOptions:nil
                                usingBlock:^(NSDraggingItem *draggingItem, NSInteger index, BOOL *stop)
 {
     NSMutableArray *videos = [NSMutableArray array];
     for (Video* video in [_arrayController selectedObjects]) {
         [videos addObject:video.url];
     }

     NSImage *draggedImage = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]iconForFiles:videos];
     NSPoint mouseLocInView = [tableView convertPoint:[tableView.window convertRectFromScreen:NSMakeRect(screenPoint.x,screenPoint.y, 0, 0)].origin fromView:nil];

     NSLog(@"Mouse location in view: X: %f, Y: %f",mouseLocInView.x, mouseLocInView.y);
     NSLog(@"Screen point: X: %f, Y:%f", screenPoint.x, screenPoint.y);

     NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
     rect.origin =draggingItem.draggingFrame.origin;
     [draggingItem setDraggingFrame:rect contents:draggedImage];
     session.draggingFormation = NSDraggingFormationDefault;
 }];}
```

Comment: Have you tried NSDraggingFormationNone ? draggingItem.draggingFrame.origin = mouseLocInView;

Comment: Yes, NSDraggingFormation has no effect and  draggingItem.draggingFrame.origin is not an assignable expression.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the app: [NSTableView](http://imgur.com/9TWtRsd)

Comment: I meant to say: use mouseLocInView as origin of the rect you are setting as dragging frame.

Comment: I use NSRect frame = [tableView frameOfCellAtColumn:0 row:insertionIndex]; raggingItem.draggingFrame = frame; in [info enumerateDraggingItemsWithOptions:0 forView:tableView classes:classes searchOptions:nil usingBlock:enumerationBlock];

Comment: I tried and still the icons shows up on a different location. Even using [draggingItem setDraggingFrame:frame]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally got it after thoroughly reading the documentation.

The doc for 
- enumerateDraggingItemsWithOptions:forView:classes:searchOptions:usingBlock: says that "forView:" argument is the view on which the coordinate system should be based for each NSDraggingItem passed. Pass nil for screen coordinate system.

What is very confusin is I was debugging by logging draggingFrame on draggingItem and couldn't figure out what frame it was. Well, it doesn't matter what is in there, if you pass nil as a view, you can set the dragging frame as screen based coordinates, the same you get when calling session.draggingLocation.

```
#define DRAG_IMAGE_WIDTH 48
#define DRAG_IMAGE_HEIGHT 48

- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
  draggingSession:(NSDraggingSession *)session
 willBeginAtPoint:(NSPoint)screenPoint
    forRowIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)rowIndexes {

    NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"tunnelfile"];

    [session enumerateDraggingItemsWithOptions:NSDraggingItemEnumerationConcurrent
                                       forView:nil
                                       classes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSPasteboardItem class]]
                                 searchOptions:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:NSPasteboardURLReadingFileURLsOnlyKey ]
                                    usingBlock:^(NSDraggingItem *draggingItem, NSInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
     {
         [draggingItem setDraggingFrame:NSMakeRect(session.draggingLocation.x-20,
                                                   session.draggingLocation.y-DRAG_IMAGE_HEIGHT+20,
                                                   DRAG_IMAGE_WIDTH,
                                                   DRAG_IMAGE_HEIGHT)
                               contents:image];
     }];
}
```

Comment: My friend, I thank you. After a year struggling with this, you have given me the direction I needed. "Pass nil for screen coordinate system." This line was the key. I opened two support tickets with apple and they were unable to give this simple answer. Again, thank you!